# How Does Software Work on Hardware?

Tags: architecture

NOTE: Please understand my question very well before giving an answer.

Simply, my question is : How software works on Hardware? where Software meets Hardware?  what is software??? I know that software is a set of instructions tell the computer hardware how to work. but, If I cannot touch Software.. it means Software is just a part of Hardware.

For example, if I have an electronic chip.. where is the software on it???? is it an electricity??

if the chip has no electricity , does that mean it has no software??
what is software????????????????  I have been writing programs for more than 4 years    but I couldn't imagine that.. it is a puzzle ..

I am really confused ..

Can anyone explain me in detail how that works?  will be thankful

Comment: You already answered your own question. " I know that software is a set of instructions tell the computer hardware how to work." Your thoughts happen in your brain, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: What about this: You can change data (software) from the machine itself, but You cannot change the hardware that way. You need some external mechanism to change the hardware. So in that sense ROM is hardware, and data on harddisk is software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software really exists at a couple of levels. One of them is human-understandable, and it's just a handy way for humans to tell hardware what to do. It's also generally at a higher level of abstraction than what a computer operates at. So you could have something like

```
if x = 5 then print "hello"
```

which is fairly easy for us carbon-based lifeforms to understand, but very difficult for a computer.

To make it simple for a computer it's run through a translator; either a compiler or an interpreter. Without getting into real deep specifics, either of these perform a set of transformations to convert this human-readable form into the very low-level instructions a computer understands to perform the same operation. These are fundamentally a set of numbers.

When these are copied into a computer and it runs them and they are the correct numbers in the correct order they would perform the comparison between x and 5 and if they were the same it would output "hello" somewhere. That simple line for us could convert to a sequence of a few hundred or thousand numbers in the computer.

As for storage, that depends on the sort of hardware. There are pieces of hardware that store data even when they are off. Think of the SD card in a camera for example: you wouldn't want your pictures to go away when your batteries run down, so they are a form of memory that stays around even when power is gone. RAM on the other hand generally loses the data when powered off. That's why we have disk drives that hold the data in magnetized form on a spinning disk - they can hold it across a power cycle so it's ready for the next power up.

Comment: Well, thank a lot for your valuable answers.

Comment: Actually, I am talking a bout a very low level. So, even the compiler/interpreter ..  it is a software. Also, the Kernel/Operating System is a software. So..  How Software meets Hardware?? Is it a magic?

Comment: To be honest, I cannot believe in Software.. except if you say it's a part of hardware.